# How to slice sublists to given length?

Tags: python, list

my problem is that the sublists of a list e.g. `l = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]` are to be sliced
to a given length, say 3. The result is supposed to look like this: `l = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7],[9,10,11]]`.
Sure you can do it like this:

```
l = [i[:3] for i in l]
```

But I would like to know: Is there even a shorter way by using only the slicing operators and by avoiding a for-loop?

Comment: I think that's the best way since slicing can't apply a function

Comment: there is no for loop  - this is a list comprehension and it won't get any better

Comment: You could use NumPy arrays (`np.array(l)[:,:3])`) if you *really* don't like list comprehension, but as it stands this line of code is already as concise as it can be.

Comment: Ok list comprehension - I am sry if I used the wrong vocabulary. The reason why I am asking is that I am fearing that a list comprehension (with a for loop) has a bad effect on the runtime especially if it is a very long list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use numpy and make `l` a ndarray (`np.array(l)`) you can do:

```py
l = l[:,:3]
```

This means: all the rows and for each row take 3 columns starting at 0.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it easier indeed. I saw a similar answer in another thread but it didnt work for me. Now I know that I hadn't converted the list to a numpy array before. :)